# How Allocator works in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

I have read https://medium.com/@vgasparyan1995/what-is-an-allocator-c8df15a93ed which he is explained how allocator works but when I implemented the following code, it always gives me 0 results. What is the problem with the code and MSVC?

Allocator.h

```
#pragma once

#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>


namespace Milad
{
    std::atomic_int GMemoryUsed(0);

    template <typename T>
    class Allocator : public std::allocator<T>
    {
    private:
        using PrBase = std::allocator<T>;
        using PrPointer = typename std::allocator_traits<PrBase>::pointer;
        using PrSizeType = typename std::allocator_traits<PrBase>::size_type;
    public:
        Allocator() = default;

        template <typename U>
        Allocator(const Allocator<U>& arg_other) : PrBase(arg_other)
        {

        }

        template <typename U>
        struct rebind
        {
            using other = Allocator<U>;
        };

        PrPointer Allocate(PrSizeType arg_n)
        {
            GMemoryUsed.fetch_add(arg_n * sizeof(T));
            return PrBase::allocate(arg_n);
        }

        void Deallocate(PrPointer arg_p, PrSizeType arg_sz)
        {
            GMemoryUsed.fetch_sub(arg_sz * sizeof(T));
            PrBase::deallocate(arg_p, arg_sz);
        }
    };
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Allocator.h"

template <template <typename T, typename AllocT> typename ContainerT>
void Measurement()
{
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Before Memory Usage: " << Milad::GMemoryUsed.load() << std::endl;
    ContainerT<int, Milad::Allocator<int>> Container;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        Container.insert(std::end(Container), i);
    }
    std::cout << "After Memory Usage: " << Milad::GMemoryUsed.load() << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename AllocT>
using SetWithDefaultComparator = std::set<T, std::less<>, AllocT>;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Measurement<std::vector>();
    Measurement<std::list>();
    Measurement<SetWithDefaultComparator>();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, it gives me the following results:

```
void __cdecl Measurement<class std::vector>(void)
Before Memory Usage: 0
After Memory Usage: 0
void __cdecl Measurement<class std::list>(void)
Before Memory Usage: 0
After Memory Usage: 0
void __cdecl Measurement<SetWithDefaultComparator>(void)
Before Memory Usage: 0
After Memory Usage: 0
```

Also, I couldn't understand how should I interpret the following lines of the code. Why these lines implemented like that:

```
template <template <typename T, typename AllocT> typename ContainerT>

ContainerT<int, Milad::Allocator<int>> Container;

template <typename T, typename AllocT>
using SetWithDefaultComparator = std::set<T, std::less<>, AllocT>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you were close. The members `allocate` and `deallocate` are members of `std::allocator` and the containers are looking for for those members. Because you have capitalized your version of the members, the default allocater is called and your memory overrides are not. Your code should be:

```
    PrPointer allocate(PrSizeType arg_n)
    {
        GMemoryUsed.fetch_add(arg_n * sizeof(T));
        return PrBase::allocate(arg_n);
    }

    void deallocate(PrPointer arg_p, PrSizeType arg_sz)
    {
        GMemoryUsed.fetch_sub(arg_sz * sizeof(T));
        PrBase::deallocate(arg_p, arg_sz);
    }
```